# Redirections in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, header, http-headers, location

If I want to redirect a user in PHP, all I've ever known to do was use the header('Location:' http://www.example.com) but I've been reading that this isn't the best way to redirect a user from page to page internally. What are some other options you can redirect a user?

Example: at the bottom it says:

> **Something Important to Remember**
>
> ...I don’t recommend, for example, using header() to bounce your users around to different pages; there are better methods that reduce the number of page loads and give the user a more fluid experience...

http://tinsology.net/2009/06/creating-a-secure-login-system-the-right-way/

Comment: you can also redirect from client side: window.url = 'newUrl';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet you provided is referring to issues where `page1.php` might execute some code followed by `header('Lodation: http://www.example.com/page2.php');` and where `page2.php` then executes some code followed by `header('Location: http://www.example.com/page3.php');` etc. This is *very* bad for user experience, and not very good for managing code either.

In cases where you genuinely **need** to redirect a user (301 redirect is probably the most common), using `header` is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I don't quite understand the difference in what your saying. Do you mean don't have 2 redirects in a row?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, multiple redirects, or redirects when an include would be more appropriate are issues. It is quite common for beginners to create a php page to do a very specific task, and then instead of using `include`, trying to use `header` to pass the user on to another page. I typically avoid headers unless I decide that I **need** to send a browser a particular header. If a page has moved permanently, use the `301` redirect header and the new location, if a resource wasn't found, send out a `404` header, and possibly populate the page with a sitemap.

Comment: I see, I try to avoid using 'includes' unless i'm including a header.php or footer.php because from my understanding it loads everything inside the 'includes' even php which would mess with load time. I understand what your saying though with the 301 and 404. I think javascript is my base option when redirecting to a custom error page though like the poster above stated.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, `includes` are the best way to make PHP modular. They're very quick. If you're making an entire library, you should be putting classes and functions into their own scripts, or at least boxing them into groups of similar functions. If you're mixing display logic with business logic, then you should read up on the MVC (Model View Controller) paradigm, because mixing view with controller is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't bad. However you could add 301 response code to make it more better, it is also better for Google to determine he should not visit that "old" site anymore.

```
<?php
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://www.new-url.com" ); 
?>
```

Comment: Well what if it is just a simple "do some code then redirect" instead of a permanent redirect?

Comment: so use it before this header and after that put there this code (2nd line)

Answer (score 0):

This is the accepted method for PHP-based redirection. If you can accomplish the redirect prior to PHP script execution, then you should - through .htaccess or server-level aliasing.

Check out the manual on `header`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

It's always sensible to avoid using `header()` internally because sometimes headers are already called.  JavaScript redirects are absolutely fine and are used systematically in a lot of web applications.  Browsers and search engines don't discriminate against or dislike JavaScript redirects.  A simple example:

```
<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="index.php"</script>'; ?>
```

Or using a variable:

```
<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="' . $page . '"</script>'; ?>
```

Comment: Well if this is true it seems like the best answer unless somebody wants to argue it.

Comment: JavaScript redirects are the *worst* way to do redirects. You ought to *know* whether headers have been called or not based on whether you've used a `header` call or whether you've sent any output with `echo` or similar. If you've partially sent output to the user, why would you want to then direct them away from that data? Additionally, any user without JavaScript enabled will not be able to follow the redirect. I would also like to see verification about SEO for JS redirects.

Comment: @Jamie, "you don't always know whether the script has previously used a `header()` function or not" [WTF are you talking about](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php)?! [Of course you can tell whether headers have been sent](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php).

Answer (score -2):

Just use

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com");
```

Comment: It does not explain why or if it's bad

Comment: What I think that the writer of the examples tries to say is that what he wrote are just examples just like he said. In most of the cases in the example it isn't necessary to do a redirect.